# Django issue with passing PK in urlconf

Tags: python, django, django-templates, blogs

Im working on a blog, i'm trying to create a comments link from each blog post, which will go a page where the individual post with comments can be seen.

In my "list.html", where all the blog posts are listed, i have this code for each blog post:

```
<div class="blogpost-comments"><a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">Comments</a></div>
```

This then submits to my URLconf shown below:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /post/5/     pk=5
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
)
```

And below my view is shown:

```
def post(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'post': post, 'user': request.user})
```

Im wanting to have the URL structure:

```
 /blog/post/{pk}/
```

To access individual posts. For some reason i'm currently getting the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog
Reverse for 'post' with arguments '(6L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog$post/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Which i don't understand. Can anybody help?

EDIT:

the main urls.py is as follow:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^blog/$', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Is that urlconf under the /blog namespace?

Comment: Yes it is in blog/urls.py

Comment: Can you show the main urls.py that includes that one?

Comment: Can you try with `{% url 'post' pk=post.id %}`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman have added the main urls.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `$` from

```
url(r'^blog/$', include('blog.urls')),
```

so that it is

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

You aren't actually including your blog urls because the regex is stopping at the `$`